# How to change TextEdit keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard

I would like to change TextEdit shortcuts which are visible in the menu, but are not listed in Keyboard shortcuts in System preferences. I tried adding new shortcut, assigned to TextEdit, but it doesn't work for some reason...
This is what I want to have:

Jump to Selection  ->  ⌥ Space

Select Line        ->  ⌘ J

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how the first one should work, but I was able to assign both custom shortcuts using this:

1. Navigate to System Preferences->Keyboard->Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Click "+" button
3. Select TextEdit as an application
4. Enter "Jump to Selection" or "Select Line…" (note that there is special … symbol used, not three periods, you can just copy and paste it from here I believe) as a menu title
5. Press shortcut you'd like to use
6. Test it and enjoy!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I tried the same, but unfortunately, for me just doesn't work. Maybe because of overlap...

Comment: Do you see the shortcuts listed next to corresponding menus? It works for me for "Jump to line" and as I noted above: not sure how "Jump to selection" works. I cannot upload images yet, so have to describe in text.

Comment: Npb, I understand you. Jump to selection actually jumps to your cursor position, without making any changes. It's very useful when you loose track of the cursor. I see only original shortcuts, not mine. However, mine are listed in system preferences. I inserted them,, just like you described. I would prefer to get into some system file and modify it directly. To see and remove original shortcuts...